# Modelica nested/combined connectors

Tags: modelica, connector

I have some Modelica components that need to be connected twice, with two different connectors (lets call them `typeAconnector` and `typeBconnector`). Is there a way to build a "super-connector" that internally uses the two connectors?

The goal would be to have

```
connect(component1.superconnector, component2.superconnector
```

automatically translated into

```
connect(component1.typeAconnector, component2.typeAconnector); 
connect(component1.typeBconnector, component2.typeBconnector);
```

Ideally, it should still be possible to do `connect(component3.typeAconnector, component2.superconnector);` and only the typeA subconnector part will be used.

I assume this is not possible, at least I have no idea where to start, any hints or workarounds or partial solutions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that be similar like the thermal machine connectors used in the MSL? The difference is, that the connectors in the MSL are of the same type, but worth a try nevertheless. See e.g. `Modelica.Electrical.Machines.Interfaces.InductionMachines.PartialThermalPortInductionMachines`

Comment: Sounds like a mix of hierarchical connector: https://www.claytex.com/blog/hierarchical-connectors-in-dymola/ and expandable connector: https://mbe.modelica.university/components/architectures/expandable/